# why my sum() function don't work for the matrix operations in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, sum

The following is my R code, I want the `tx[1, 1] =  1*2^1 + 4*5^2 + 7*8^3`, `tx[1, 2] = 4*5 + 7*8^2`, `tx[1, 3] = 7*8`，but it only including `7*8^3` for `tx[1, 1]` and `7*8^2` for `tx[1, 2]`. The other elements in the tx matrix only include the last term in the sum operation too. So,could anyone tell me how to rectify my code to have a correct output? Thanks in advance!

```
A <- matrix(c(1:9),ncol=3)
B <- matrix(c(2:10),ncol=3)
tx<-matrix(rep(NA,3*3),3,3)

for(j in 1:3)
{
  for(i in 1:3)

  {
    for(k in 1:3-i+1)
    {
      tx[j,i]<-sum(A[j,k+i-1]*(B[j,k+i-1])^k)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it gives you the final output but `for(k in 1:3-i+1)` should be `for(k in 1:(3-i+1))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Ronak, but the answer is no.

Comment: You want `tx[j,i] <- tx[j,i] + A[j,k+i-1] * (B[j,k+i-1])^k`. But initialise the tx with zeros, not NA. `tx <- matrix(rep(0, 3*3), 3, 3)`

Comment: @Edward, thank you very much. I get the right output now!

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's not summing the results of each loop, just saving out whatever the last loop result happens to be. Try this instead:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:9),ncol=3)
B <- matrix(c(2:10),ncol=3)
tx<-matrix(rep(0,3*3),3,3)

for(j in 1:3)
{
  for(i in 1:3)

  {
    for(k in 1:3-i+1)
    {
      tx[j,i]<-tx[j,i] + (A[j,k+i-1]*(B[j,k+i-1])^k)
    }
  }
}
```

I initialized the tx matrix to start at 0 and added the result of each loop to the existing total, so that it increments over each loop.

Comment: Yes, thank you@ryelv, your answer is the same as Edward.